# Cannot run heroku db:push

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite, taps

I'm trying to push my database to heroku runnig command and have an error

```
~ heroku db:push
  Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
  !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
  !    On most systems this will be:
  !    
  !    sudo gem install taps
```

I'm using rvm so I run

```
  gem install taps
```

Than nothing happens and running

```
   heroku db:push
```

leads to the same error

I use ruby 1.9.3 but for the purposes of db pushing I run command

```
 rvm use 1.9.2-p290@mygemset
```

Gemsets in1.9.2 and 1.9.3 are identical

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not install the taps gem with sudo as they suggest. use the rvm sets and just install in the wanted rvm using `gem install taps`

that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with reinstalling GCC-10.7 for Mac and reinstalling rvm with 1.9.2 ruby

Comment: This worked although this does not seem like a qualified method since you have no clue what went wrong. therefor this topic will not help anyone else.